# Stress during unloading in FEM simulation of an elasto-plastic truss element

Tags: finite-element, simulation

I am simulating the behaviour of a single bar composed of two node points by fixing one point and applying a force on the oder node with $F_x = 1$ and fixing $u_y=0$. I am assuming the material to behave elasto plastic with isotropic hardening.

My loading simulation for $F_x = 0$ to $F_x = 1$ with increment $1/10$ seems to be okay, my unloading process with same increment size is somehow weird. Maybe I am wrong but the stress should be $0$ for $F_x = 0$ again, right?.

[image: loading process]

[image: whole simulation]

Comment: The thing that you are seeing here if you correctly formulated it, just showing you a typical elasto-plastic material behavior. When you go to plastic deformation region you have some **permanent** deformation or strain that will remain there even if you remove the load, so it's pretty normal to have a non-zero strain when your force is zero.

Comment: Hey @AloneProgrammer, a non-zero strain when force is zero i clear for me. But how about a non-zero stress when force is zero? (Under the assumption the starting stress is zero)

Comment: Maybe this has to do with the rheological model (check the model on Figure 1.b:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263414110_Numerical_analysis_of_dynamic_behaviour_of_elastoplastic_beams/related). In this model, above the yield stress you will have a remaining stress because the slider prevent the spring (only the one connected in parallel to the slider) returning to its original position which creates a permanent stress even after unloading.

Comment: @LoveFrootLoops That's called residual stress :)

Comment: Theresore it seems to be normal? I just used a single truss element with an external force (i.e. traction) in one direction. For the elasto plasticity I used the a return mapping algorithm.